# In beamer, insert the table of contents as table in frame headline

Tags: tables, beamer, table-of-contents, themes, headline

I am preparing my presentation in `beamer`.

In my presentation, I need most of the frame area, so I need to modify template headline.

I use `Warsaw` theme and `split` `outertheme`. Because my sections and subsections are so many, in this `outertheme` headline takes so much space from top of the frame.

I want to modify `headline` and insert the list of sections and subsections of the current section in table form. In this table I want the current section and subsection to be highlighted.

Something like the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a compilable example with your current settings. Note that the `miniframes` theme may save some space for you